# onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) in prime faces is not getting me updated value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, roweditor

I am trying to update the row using the jsf with primefaces here is my code for each files but when I debug I am not getting updated value it gives me an old value every-time and persist it same as an old one.

`user-type.xhtml`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body style="align:center;">

    <div style="width: 100%">
        <h:form id="form">
            <div style="float: left; width: 54%;">
                <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
                <p:dataTable id="userTypesTbl" var="varUserType"
                    value="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.userTypeMasters}" editable="true"
                    style="margin-bottom:20px" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
                    <f:facet name="header">User Type Managging</f:facet>

                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.onRowEdit}"
                        update=":form:msgs" />
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                        listener="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.onRowCancel}" update=":form:msgs" />

                    <p:column headerText="Sr.">
                        #{rowIndex+1}.
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Type">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{varUserType.type}" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <p:inputText value="#{varUserType.type}" style="width:100%"
                                    label="type" />
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">View</f:facet>
                        <p:commandButton update=":form" oncomplete="userTypeDialog.show()"
                            icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{userType}"
                                var="#{selectedUserType}"
                                target="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.selectedUserType}" />
                        </p:commandButton>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:32px;">
                        <f:facet name="header">Edit</f:facet>
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column style="width:32px;align-items: center;">
                        <f:facet name="header">Delete</f:facet>
                        <h:commandLink
                            action="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.deleteAction(varUserType)}">
                            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="delete.png" height="45%"
                                width="50%" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <ui:debug hotkey="x" />

                <p:dialog header="User type detail" widgetVar="userTypeDialog"
                    resizable="false" width="330" showEffect="explode"
                    hideEffect="explode">
                    <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
                        <h:outputText value="ID : " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.selectedUserType.id}" />
                        <h:outputText value="TYPE: " />
                        <h:outputText value="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.selectedUserType.type}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>
            </div>
            <div style="float: right; width: 44%;">
                <p:panel menuTitle="Add User Type." header="Add User Type.">
                    <h:outputText value="User type *:" />
                    <p:inputText value="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.userType}"
                        title="Enter User Type.." id="myUserType"
                        style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;"></p:inputText>
                    <p:commandButton value="Add Type"
                        action="#{userTypeTabMenuBean.saveAction}" ajax="false">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:panel>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`UserTypeTabMenuBean.java`

```
package com.convoy.gpack.managedbean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import com.convoy.gpack.dao.UserTypeMasterDAO;
import com.convoy.gpack.pack.models.UserTypeMaster;

@ManagedBean(name = "userTypeTabMenuBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserTypeTabMenuBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1467465633405172689L;
private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(UserTypeTabMenuBean.class);
private List<UserTypeMaster> userTypeMasters;
private UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
private UserTypeMaster selectedUserType;
private String userType;

public List<UserTypeMaster> getUserTypeMasters() {
    userTypeMasters = userTypeMasterDAO.getAllUserTypes();
    logger.info("getUserTypeMasters=" + userTypeMasters);
    return userTypeMasters;
}

public String deleteAction(UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster) {
    logger.info("Deleting the object with id = " + userTypeMaster.getId());
    UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
    int result = userTypeMasterDAO.deleteUserType(userTypeMaster);
    userTypeMasters.remove(userTypeMaster);
    if (result == 1) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "User type deleted successfuly.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    } else {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed to delete user types.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
    return null;
}

public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
    UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster = (UserTypeMaster) event.getObject();
    logger.info("UPDATING THE USER TYPE MASTER : "
            + userTypeMaster.getType());
    UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
    userTypeMasterDAO.saveOrUpdateUserTypeMaster(userTypeMaster);
    logger.info("UPDATING THE USER TYPE MASTER : "
            + userTypeMaster.getType());

    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edited type ",
            ((UserTypeMaster) event.getObject()).getType() + "");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Editing Cancelled for ",
            ((UserTypeMaster) event.getObject()).getType() + "");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}

public UserTypeMaster getSelectedUserType() {
    return selectedUserType;
}

public void setSelectedUserType(UserTypeMaster selectedUserType) {
    this.selectedUserType = selectedUserType;
}

public String getUserType() {
    return userType;
}

public void setUserType(String userType) {
    this.userType = userType;
}

public void saveAction() {
    logger.info("Saving the object to database...." + userType);
    if (userType.trim().length() < 1) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Can not save empty user type.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
    UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
    UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster = new UserTypeMaster();
    userTypeMaster.setType(userType);
    int result = userTypeMasterDAO
            .saveOrUpdateUserTypeMaster(userTypeMaster);
    if (result == 1) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User type saved.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    } else {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed to save user type.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
}
```

`UserTypeMasterDAO.java`

```
package com.convoy.gpack.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.convoy.gpack.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil;
import com.convoy.gpack.pack.models.UserTypeMaster;

public class UserTypeMasterDAO implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4005898944892506760L;

public UserTypeMaster getUserTypeById(long long1) {

    return null;
}

public List<String> getAllUserTypesInString() {
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserTypeMaster.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<UserTypeMaster> userTypeMasters = criteria.list();
        List<String> userTypeMastersString = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster : userTypeMasters) {
            userTypeMastersString.add(userTypeMaster.getType());
        }
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return userTypeMastersString;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public List<UserTypeMaster> getAllUserTypes() {
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserTypeMaster.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<UserTypeMaster> userTypeMasters = criteria.list();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return userTypeMasters;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public int saveOrUpdateUserTypeMaster(UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster) {
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        userTypeMaster.setType(userTypeMaster.getType().toUpperCase());
        session.saveOrUpdate(userTypeMaster);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }

}

public int deleteUserType(UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster) {
    try {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(userTypeMaster);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance ~ :)

Comment: There are several posts on SO on this and in general on the internet. Check those and get back with the links and why each did not work for you

Comment: Dear @Kukeltje after a long googling I had posted the question but finally I got the clue of `@PostConstruct` annotation BTW thanks for your response. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly Primefaces follows strict structure and I think it is compulsory to add init() method with @PostConstruct annotation.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    userTypeMasters = userTypeMasterDAO.getAllUserTypes();
}
```

Here is the solution.

```
package com.convoy.gpack.managedbean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import com.convoy.gpack.dao.UserTypeMasterDAO;
import com.convoy.gpack.pack.models.UserTypeMaster;

@ManagedBean(name = "userTypeTabMenuBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserTypeTabMenuBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1467465633405172689L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(UserTypeTabMenuBean.class);
    private List<UserTypeMaster> userTypeMasters;
    private UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
    private UserTypeMaster selectedUserType;
    private String userType;

// This is the required method to get the datatable list.
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        userTypeMasters = userTypeMasterDAO.getAllUserTypes();
        logger.info("getUserTypeMasters=" + userTypeMasters);
    }

    public List<UserTypeMaster> getUserTypeMasters() {
        return userTypeMasters;
    }

    public String deleteAction(UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster) {
        logger.info("Deleting the object with id = " + userTypeMaster.getId());
        UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
        int result = userTypeMasterDAO.deleteUserType(userTypeMaster);
        userTypeMasters.remove(userTypeMaster);
        if (result == 1) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                    "User type deleted successfuly.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed to delete user types.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
        UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster = (UserTypeMaster) event.getObject();
        logger.info("UPDATING THE USER TYPE MASTER : "
                + userTypeMaster.getType());
        UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
        userTypeMasterDAO.saveOrUpdateUserTypeMaster(userTypeMaster);
        logger.info("UPDATING THE USER TYPE MASTER : "
                + userTypeMaster.getType());

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Edited type ",
                ((UserTypeMaster) event.getObject()).getType() + "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public void onRowCancel(RowEditEvent event) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Editing Cancelled for ",
                ((UserTypeMaster) event.getObject()).getType() + "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

    public UserTypeMaster getSelectedUserType() {
        return selectedUserType;
    }

    public void setSelectedUserType(UserTypeMaster selectedUserType) {
        this.selectedUserType = selectedUserType;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public void saveAction() {
        logger.info("Saving the object to database...." + userType);
        if (userType.trim().length() < 1) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Can not save empty user type.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
        UserTypeMasterDAO userTypeMasterDAO = new UserTypeMasterDAO();
        UserTypeMaster userTypeMaster = new UserTypeMaster();
        userTypeMaster.setType(userType);
        int result = userTypeMasterDAO
                .saveOrUpdateUserTypeMaster(userTypeMaster);
        if (result == 1) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User type saved.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            init();
        } else if (result == -2) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("User type already exist..");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed to save user type.");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

That's it~ :)

Thanks @Swathi for the hint.

Comment: You are initialize the userTypeMasters in the init method but never use It in the Controller. Please update your answer with the View file, where you used userTypeMasters.

Answer (score 4):

Think it might be because of the database values list

```
#{userTypeTabMenuBean.userTypeMasters}
```

this always retrieves from the database and that is why getObject() returned an old value ( actually the value from the database)

update the method getUserTypeMasters() as follows

```
if (userTypeMasters == null){

        userTypeMasters = userTypeMasterDAO.getAllUserTypes();

}

return userTypeMasters ;
```

Comment: +1  Yes @Swathi you are too close to the answer and I am posting the real solution which is about the init()  method...